# Global variables vs declaring variables globally

Tags: php, include, global-variables

I am in a situation where I need to store every visitors IP address for some processing. I know sessions can do the job really well, but I don't want this data to be stored in any form of cookie, session anywhere. I need this data to be destroyed, as soon as the page is existed/closed.

So, my intention is to create a `global.php` file and just store it in a variable, this file then will be placed at the top of every page. (bad practice, I know)

Now, there are two ways I can store information in this file. One is using the `global $var` (which does not make sense, since it is accessible anywhere), another is is just simply initializing a `$variable` Now, since this `global.php` file will be added on top of every page, it makes the advantages of using a super global variable trivial.

Now, if you are asking why I have not just used `global $var` to begin with is because, I have been hearing how bad they are, and they should be avoided .....

So, the with this negative talk, the advantage of using `global $var` has diminished and now I can't see, what is more appropriate to use in this scenario.

## ..in a nutshell.

When you declare a variable inside a file, and you share that file in every script, what difference (performance) does it make whether you declare that variable as is or using the `global` keyword.

Comment: There is no such thing as `$_GLOBAL` I think you meant [`$GLOBALS`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)?

Comment: Sorry, actually I mean `global $var` silly mistake :)

Comment: I doubt there's a remarkable difference unless you're planning to have 2,000,000 variables or something like that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Thanks. I am just trying to store one or two values, so does the negative sentiment about using `global` have any effect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As luck would have it, PHP already provides users' IP addresses in a super global array which is accessible by every function:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

You don't need to worry about creating an alternate global variable to store this data.

That said, I think you may have a misunderstanding about what including a file wiwth `GLOBALS` in it does. Variables initialized or modified in a script will expire as soon as the script is complete... it is only global in so far as all functions on the page can access it. `global` or `$GLOBALS` variables only exists in the scope of the current script (page).. if you want variables shared across multiple pages you **must** uses sessions or a session-like approach (which is to say that the variable must be stored and retrieved from the servers filesystem or a database.

### Response to edits in the question

If you're simply concerned about the performance differences between reading a variable and reading a variable out of a global array, the answer is "don't worry about it" - technically reading out of a global array should be slower, but in all the benchmarking tests I've seen on the subject there is no actual performance difference even when dealing with large numbers of variables.

And if you're interesting in why you keep hearing people mumble stuff about globals being bad, [read this article by Tom Hudson](http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it) -  basically there are a few different ways in which you can get into trouble when using globals (especially on large, complex systems) but it's very dependent on case specifics.

Comment: I didn't phrase it better. I know about the server variables, and the IP is always keep inside the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` What I meant to ask is added in the question with more clarity